# Using binary file stored in storage account from python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to run a `python script` (the script resides on a directory in \wwwroot directory in my app file system) from my web app using `java`, the script uses a `binary file` (`g.bin`), the binary file size is huge (`3.5+ GB`), so I stored it in a storage account (file service), now I want to use the data found in the bin file, How can I open the file using my script? What is the path that the `python script` should use and how to open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use azure-storage python SDK, and the module you need is [`azure.storage.file.fileservice`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.file.fileservice.html)

First initialize the FileService

```
f = FileService(account_name=None, account_
                key=None, sas_token=None,
                protocol=’https’, endpoint_
                suffix=’core.windows.net’,
                request_session=None, connection_
                string=None)
```

Then you need to download the file to a stream using `fileservice.get_file_to_stream` method.

```
f.get_file_to_stream(share_name, directory_name, file_name, stream, start_range=None, end_range=None, validate_content=False, progress_callback=None, max_connections=2, timeout=None, snapshot=None)
```

Give that a try. If you can't get it to work, update your question with what you tried, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you, I need to read the binary file using word2vec like that : 

`model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('site/wwwroot/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True, limit = 100000)
`
what is the url in this case? I got no such file or directory.